# Close Application to System Tray

Tags: wpf, system-tray

I have a WPF app with an exit "X" button only. A system tray icon is launched when the application starts up. I would like to either "hide" or close the main window to the system tray when "X" is clicked. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have probably been searching with the wrong key words.  Try a Google search for WPF NotifyIcon, and you'll find abundant resources.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you need to do is change the `ShutdownMode` for your `Application` to `OnExplicitShutdown`. You can set it in `App.xaml` and then the app will stay alive until you call `Application.Shutdown()` from code (probably based on some explicit user command). How you handle reopening the window from the tray icon is dependent on your specific implementation but that should at least get you started.